# Using jmockit to mock constructor that throws error: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, noclassdeffounderror, jmockit

Jmockit is very powerful, but sometimes I cannot understand what it does behind the scene, so I have a question regarding jmockit. Hopefully the more experienced programmers on here could help shine some light on this situation :)

I have the following two classes in two separate files:

```
public class SmallClass {
    String a;
    SmallClass(String arg) throws Exception {
        a = arg;
    }
    public String getString() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class BigClass {
    private static final SmallClass smallClass;
    static {
        try {
            smallClass = new SmallClass("dummy");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not initialized", e);
        }
    }
    public static String getString() {
        return smallClass.getString();
    }
}
```

Now, I have a class to test BigClass:

```
public class BigClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception {
        ///CLOVER:OFF
        new MockUp<SmallClass>() {
            @Mock
            public void $init(String string) throws Exception {
                //Do nothing
            }
            @Mock
            public String getString() {
                return "dummyString";
            }
        };
        ///CLOVER:ON
        Assert.assertEquals("dummyString", BigClass.getString());
    }

    @Test(expected = ExceptionInInitializerError.class)
    public void testException() throws Exception {
        ///CLOVER:OFF
        new MockUp<SmallClass>() {
            @Mock
            public void $init(String string) throws Exception{
                throw new Exception("Mocked Exception");
            }
        };
        ///CLOVER:ON
        BigClass.getString();
    }
}
```

If I run each of these independently, then they each passes. But if I run the whole test file, then the first test fails with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class BigClass
```

I also tried tearing down the mock after each test like this, but it doesn't help:

```
public class BigClassTest {
    MockUp<SmallClass> smallClassMockUp;

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception {
        ///CLOVER:OFF
        smallClassMockUp = new MockUp<SmallClass>() {
            @Mock
            public void $init(String string) throws Exception {
                //Do nothing
            }
            @Mock
            public String getString() {
                return "dummyString";
            }
        };
        ///CLOVER:ON
        Assert.assertEquals("dummyString", BigClass.getString());
        smallClassMockUp.tearDown();
    }

    @Test(expected = ExceptionInInitializerError.class)
    public void testException() throws Exception {
        ///CLOVER:OFF
        smallClassMockUp = new MockUp<SmallClass>() {
            @Mock
            public void $init(String string) throws Exception{
                throw new Exception("Mocked Exception");
            }
        };
        ///CLOVER:ON
        BigClass.getString();
        smallClassMockUp.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The occurrence of `NoClassDefFoundError`, in a case like this, is not because the class wasn't found by the JVM (it was), but because its static initialization has failed (by throwing an exception or error from the execution of a static initializer). Once this happens, the class is left in an invalid/uninitialized state and cannot be used in the same JVM instance anymore.

For reference, see the ["Initialization of classes and interfaces"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) section in the JLS.

Also, note that the order in which tests execute is not necessarily the textual order they appear in the test class. Here, `testException` (the second test) runs first. So, when `testGet` runs, the class is invalid and the JVM throws the error.

Comment: So how would I write my unit tests to test both cases where the constructor throws an exception in the static block and where it does not?

Comment: I don't see a need to *have* the test where static initialization fails. Note that `catch` block in the static initializer of `BigClass` is just for the compiler's sake.